# Query images in object storage by metadata

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openstack-swift, object-storage

I have over 10GB of images for my ecommerce app. I think move them to object storage (S3, Azure, Google, etc.).

So I will have an opportunity to add custom data to metadata (like NOSQL). For example, I have an image and corresponding metadata: product_id, sku, tags.

I want to query my images by metadata? For example, `get all images from my object storage where meta_key = 'tag' and tag = 'nature'`

So, object storage should have indexing capabilities. **I do not want to iterate over billion of images to find only one of them.**

I'm new to amazon aws, azure, google, openstack. I know that Amazon S3 is able to store metadata, but It doesn't have indexes (like Apache Solr).

What service is best suited to query files|objects by custom metadata?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in AWS your best best is going to be to pair the object store (S3) with a traditional database to store the meta data for easy querying.

Depending on your needs DynamoDB or RDS (in the flavor of your choice) would be 2 AWS technologies to consider for the meta-data storage and retrieval.